# Wordpress reads jQuery but its methods won't work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, methods

I'm working in Wordpress with a theme called DIVI. I'm pasting some jQuery code that works perfectly fine in CodePen, but then I paste it inside the "Code" module, the code snippet works fine but it doesn't run methods like fadeIn() and delay().

$ selector works perfect, for which I assume it is reading jQuery.

Any ideas?

Here's a piece of code, just in case. So in this case '.span3' it's getting filled with the html text provided, but hide(), fadeIn() and .delay() won't work

```
$('#b1').click(function(){
  $('.span3').hide().html("Post-purchase & Onboarding").fadeIn(1200).delay(600);
});
```

Comment: Try changing the shorthand "$" to "JQuery".

Comment: @zipkundan It behaves the same way

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are there other animations running aswell?

Comment: @Michael No errors in the console. There're no other animations running, no. I'm in contact with DIVI support, but I just don't understand how something could be blocking parts of jQuery, doesn't make sense.